# Are there portions of the Microsoft .NET Core library that are hidden in the .dll files?

Tags: c#, cil

Some of the methods inside the mscorlib.dll seem to be empty when I look through them.

I was reading about the MSIL and was using the IL DASM in Visual Studio to look through some of the class methods. Out of curiosity I went probing into some of the Math class methods and found some of them to be empty.

Here is the code from the Math.ABS()...

```
.method public hidebysig static int32  Abs(int32 'value') cil managed
{
  .custom instance void __DynamicallyInvokableAttribute::.ctor() = ( 01 00 00 00 ) 
  // Code size       13 (0xd)
  .maxstack  8
  IL_0000:  ldarg.0
  IL_0001:  ldc.i4.0
  IL_0002:  blt.s      IL_0006
  IL_0004:  ldarg.0
  IL_0005:  ret
  IL_0006:  ldarg.0
  IL_0007:  call       int32 System.Math::AbsHelper(int32)
  IL_000c:  ret
} // end of method Math::Abs
```

And here is the code found in the Math.Sin()...

```
.method public hidebysig static float64  Sin(float64 a) cil managed internalcall
{
  .custom instance void System.Security.SecuritySafeCriticalAttribute::.ctor() = ( 01 00 00 00 ) 
  .custom instance void __DynamicallyInvokableAttribute::.ctor() = ( 01 00 00 00 ) 
} // end of method Math::Sin
```

I have a suspicion it has to do with that System.Security.SecuritySafeCriticalAttribute constuctor, but I am not sure what that does even after reading the MSDN page on it, or why it would hide IL code.

Does anyone have any insight to what I am seeing?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

`internalcall` indicates the method is implemented by the CLR directly rather than in IL.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. I had not seen that. Thank you. I will look into this further, then.

Comment: [ecalllist.h](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/vm/ecalllist.h) is the place to start looking for `InternalCall` implementations.